# Exception in the Socket#33711845::DoBind - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

I'm attempting to setup a simple remoting windows service and getting the following error when starting the service:

```
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [4180] Exception in the Socket#33711845::DoBind - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4180] ExclusiveTcpListener#4032828::Start()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4180] Socket#33711845::Bind(0:9998#9998)
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [4180] Exception in the Socket#33711845::DoBind - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

In the windows service application I have the following code in the "OnStart" method - the error occurs when registering the Channel - ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpPipe, true); As far as I can tell there are no other processes using port 9998 ...

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        int portNumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endPointTCPPort"]);

        TcpChannel tcpPipe = new TcpChannel(portNumber);

        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpPipe, true);

        Type serviceType = Type.GetType("TractionGatewayService.TractionGateway");

        try
        {
           RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(serviceType, "updateCustomerDetails", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
        }
        catch (RemotingException e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("unable to establish listening port because " + e.message; 
            ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(tcpPipe);
        }
```

Comment: I'm occasionally having the exact same problem with remoting in a windows service. Try to run netstat -b and check which process is owning your port and which state it is in? In my case, SYSTEM is the owner with port state 'ESTABLISHED' and the workaround is a reboot of the system.

Comment: Hi Dag, thanks for your reply. I have run netstat but there is no mention of the port I'm attempting to use - 9998. Before I created a "windows service" I wrote this code to run under a console window. I can run the console code using port 9998 without any problems - I only get this error when running the above code under a windows service. I probably should have mentioned that I've installed this service on my workstation.

Comment: glad you found your problem. For the benefit of others reading this, I'll remark that .NET Remoting is now deprecated in favor of WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I had two seperate calls to TcpChannel to register the port - hence the error. 
thanks to everyone who has taken a look at this. 
...